# String returned by FHIR service shows in variable and has length but does not print (or prints as white space) in logging

Tags: rest, slf4j, hl7-fhir

- I'm making a REST request to a FHIR service.
- I get a response
- The response has a length
- I can append "foo\n" to the beginning of the string and "\bar" to the end
- But when I log the string I get this:

[image]

- If I copy and paste the output show above the string is there when a paste it into a document
- I'm using @Slf4j

Why is the text not visible?

Comment: What does the text look like in a browser?  It's possible for a string to be only whitespace.  (It's not encouraged, but it's not strictly prohibited)

Comment: It's funny, the string is totally there.  It's a long string and shows up as a couple of blank rows.  If I copy and paste the logging output into a text editor it magically appears.

Comment: I think it is a problem with the logger/eclipse and totally unrelated to FHIR/REST